# Obtain access to a controller from a child directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a small angular application that needs to list a list of entities (endpoints in my case). The entities are saved in an array. For the purpose of this example, let's say they're on the controller.

To better separate the logic, I created two directives: `endpointList` and endpoint, like this:

the directives are declared like this:

```
 myApp.directive('endpointList', function () {
        return {
            restrict:'EA',
            controller:'EndpointCtrl',
            controllerAs:'epCtrl',
            transclude: true,
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'endpoint-list.html'
        };
    })
    .directive('endpoint', function ($compile, $log) {
        return {
            scope: {
                scope:'=ngModel',
                func:'&',
                index:'@'
            },
            restrict:'EA',
            replace:true,
            templateUrl: 'endpoint.html',
            require:'?^endpointList',
            compile: function(tElem, tAtt) {
                return function(scope, el, attr, ctrl) {
                    // ctrl.addResource(scope);
                }
            }
        };
    });
```

the template for `endpoint-list.html`

```
...
<section>
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectAll" ng-click="toggleSelectAll()"/></th>
                <th>Label</th>
                <th>Last updated</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Sync</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-transclude></tbody>
    </table>
</section>
...
```

the template for `endpoint.html`:

```
...
<td>
    <a ng-click="sync()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud">CALL ME</a>
</td>
...
```

and I use them like this:

```
<endpoint-list>
    <endpoint ng-repeat="ep in endpoints" scope="ep" ng-model="ep" func="selectEp(scope)" index="{{$index}}"></end-point>
</endpoint-list>
```

My problem is that in the endpoint.html I have a link that, when clicked, I want it to call the function sync() on the controller:

```
$scope.sync = function(endpoint) {
    console.log('syncing:');
    console.log(endpoint);
};
```

How can I do that? Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Here's the plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/js7syyZ8u0i9KoOIgwdQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a service as a middle man, inject it in both your controller and directive, and that's it. You'll be able to call that service's method directly from your directive's template, provided that your controller has a reference to your service.

```
myApp.service("middleManService", function() {
    this.sync = function(endpoint) {
        console.log('syncing:');
        console.log(endpoint);
    };

        this.test = 'blah';

        this.selectAll = false;
        this.deleteBtnVisible = false;
        this.editBtnVisible = false;

        this.endpoints = [
            {
                label: '2.2.0',
                url: 'https://version-2_2_0-api.company.com/test/test?api_key=xxx',
                selected: false
            },
            {
                label: '2.3.0',
                url: 'https://version-2_3_0-api.company.com/test/test?api_key=xxx',
                selected: false
            }
        ];
    };
});
```

Add the reference to this service to your controller :

```
 myApp.controller('EndpointCtrl',    
    function ($scope, middleManService) {
        $scope.middleManService = middleManService;
```

And then in your html, call it like this :

```
    <td>
        <a ng-click="middleManService.sync()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud">CALL ME</a>
    </td>
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, the ng-click="sync()" doesn't work. adding a middleware service shouldn't make a difference, should it not?

Comment: since you have a reference to to the middleware service in your controller, middleManService.sync() will directly call your service function, provided that that the directive is loaded in a page whose controller is the same as the one in which you have added the reference of the service. This will definitely work ..

Comment: maybe I misinterpreted your answer, or forgot to add something. If you can fork the plunkr and ajust it as necessary, I'd be very thankful. Thanks

Comment: I also tried doing `middleman: '=middlemanService'` just like here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive with customerInfo. Still doesn't work. I'm missing something trivial

Comment: ok, I figured it out. My problem was the directive. The sync function should have been mentioned like this: `sync: '&'`. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad it helped (y).. :)